# Where/what is Error.ArgumentNull()?

Tags: c#, .net

Sometimes I see this in code samples:

```
throw Error.ArgumentNull("someParameter");
```

There's an example [here](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs), on line 89.

I'd like to use `Error` in my own code. Where can I find it?

(I tried to find it on my own, I tried `using` the namespaces at the top of that file, and I tried to get Visual Studio to locate it, so far no luck.)

Comment: I favor even less boilerplate, using a helper method to handle the `if` *and* the `throw`. Ex: `ArgumentHelper.ThrowIfNull(arg, "name");` (which could be an extension method, of course.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a helper class defined by the creators of the library to make their lives easier.

**[Error.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/Common/Error.cs) file:**

```
internal static ArgumentNullException ArgumentNull(string parameterName, string messageFormat, params object[] messageArgs)
{
    return new ArgumentNullException(parameterName, Error.Format(messageFormat, messageArgs));
}
```

---

If you are looking for similar functionality, take a look at [Code Contracts](https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) (for non-Express editions of Visual Studio). Then you can write something like this:

```
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

void MyMethod(string someParameter)
{
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(someParameter != null);

    // ...
}
```

...and it will throw an exception at run-time when this condition has not been met.

Answer (score 5):

It is an internal helper class, with `internal` visibility. That's why you haven't been able to locate it.

Microsoft source code uses this pattern in a variety of places.

But why do it? It enables you to throw a consistent, nicely-formatted, localized exception without having to put that logic in every exception handler.

Taking that a step further, some definitions even contain compiler directives, such as:

```
        internal static ArgumentException InvalidEnumArgument( string parameterName, int invalidValue, Type enumClass ) {
#if NETFX_CORE
            return new ArgumentException(Error.Format(CommonWebApiResources.InvalidEnumArgument, parameterName, invalidValue, enumClass.Name), parameterName);
#else
            return new InvalidEnumArgumentException( parameterName, invalidValue, enumClass );
#endif
        }
```

Other methods (such as `PropertyNull()`) are decorated with code analysis suppression messages.

Again, it's simply a convenience/consistency mechanism to avoid repeating this code all over the place.

I probably wouldn't suggest trying to use this exact code in your own project, because your needs will be different. But you can certainly use it as a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

That is a custom internal type, it does not exist in the BCL.

```
namespace System.Web.Http
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Utility class for creating and unwrapping <see cref="Exception"/> instances.
    /// </summary>
    internal static class Error
    {}
 }
```

You can copy it from there and you it if you want.